# ASIHTTP auth token expiring

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in my iOS app. Each POST request requires a valid auth token to be present. I get the auth token form the server by making an auth/ request on the opening on the app.

The auth token expires every 30 minutes or so. I get a 301 error in the response if I need a new token, then I make the auth/ request again to get a new valid token.

This is the problem I am running into: I POST something, say a photo upload, to the server, and get back a 301 because it is time to get a new auth token. I make that auth/ request, but then I lose my original request for the new auth token. I can figure out a way to persist that old request and start again when the new token is in place, but I figure there is an easier/better way to do this within the framework, something that automatically starts my original request again after getting the valid token.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a good solution. What I'm going is adding the ASIHTTPRequest object to an array. In fact, I add all requests to the array and delete them when they've been successfully processed. Some code to demonstrate:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *asiRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
asiRequest.delegate = self;
[asiRequest addPostValue:value forKey:@"key"];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];

if (!requests) {
    requests = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
[requests addObject:asiRequest];
```

So now you have the request object in an array. When the request finishes, if I need to get a new auth token, I make a request for it, get it, then cycle through the requests array and make those requests with the new auth token like so:

```
for (ASIFormDataRequest *asiRequest in requests) {
     [asiRequest startAsynchronous];
 }
```